# Bring <div> "infront" of parent <div>, but make JS skip it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the `div` `slidestatic` really static. I don't want it to shrink with the other divs. When I make the `z-index` of the parent -1, I don't have access to the `<a href>`s anymore, I can't click them. Thanks

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g2bsgaka/)

Comment: Which `<a>` tags are you talking about? I can access all the links. Kindly tell us how to replicate. `:)`

Comment: there are 5 `<a>` tags and they are all the same. I am talking about the navigation of the "slider"

Comment: Er... There's a slider? Where's the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply The position property to the slidestatic div. Change slidestatic div to direct child of slider div and add style "position:fixed to slidestatic div.

```
#slidestatic {
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
}
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/ef72x7b1/)

Hope this will fix your problem.

An alternative way is to add animation to the description div.
Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/ef72x7b1/2/)

Comment: `position: fixed;` doesn't work for me, because it is not only the slider on that page. There is more content and I don't want the slider navigation to scroll with the other stuff on the page.

Comment: Then you need to put animation to the description div. Also add background image to the same.